# Restoring Macbook Lion Boot

Tags: mac, boot, osx-lion, refit

Recently I installed Ubuntu on my Macbook Pro with Lion.  I had trouble getting it to work with my hardware and repartitioned the drive to eliminate Ubuntu.  Now when I boot my mac I get an error about grub not existing.  The only way I can boot into Lion is by holding the option key, going to rEFIT and selecting Lion.  How can I eliminate grub and rEFIT and restore the original Lion boot without reinstalling lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log into your Mac partition open Terminal and then type in:

```
sudo fdisk -u /dev/disk0
```

That should do the trick.  Reference [fdisk Manual Page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/fdisk.8.html).  It should be noted that messing with the MBR can be dangerous and I would advise having a backup.